# Why can't I use empathic do in present perfect?

Tags: grammar

> He hasn't told me anything.
>
> He **doesn't** have told me anything.
>
> She has arrived.
>
> She **does** have arrived.

**While with the possessive *have* I can use the empathic *do:***

> He does have a car.
>
> She does have a cat

I know I might sound dumb but I just asked it out of curiosity :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the emphatic *do* in the present perfect because it is the auxiliary verb which is used for the Present Simple tense.

In the sentences "He does have a car" and "She does have a cat," *have* is the main verb, while *do* is auxiliary used in the affirmative sentences for emphasis.

*Have* can function as a main verb or as an auxiliary verb too. In present perfect sentences *have/has* is the auxiliary verb.

We don't use 2 auxiliary verbs in a sentence like that. That's why "he doesn't have told me anything" makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you btw you made a typo. You were to say “you cant" I guess :3

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin No, I really meant "have" can function as a main verb or as an auxiliary verb. For example, in "I have a car" "have" is the main verb" and in "I have done it" "have" is auxiliary.

Comment: I know that. Re read your answer please. You wrote can's

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin oh, that's right! Thank you!

Comment: I think the way native speakers of English – I am not one – would put emphasis on a present perfect is simply by stressing the auxiliary "have/has" in speech, and italicizing it in writing.