# What do we call these kind of structures?

Tags: negation, do-support

> I don't have Instagram installed on my phone.

Does it mean the same as

> I haven't installed Instagram on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have Instagram installed on my phone.

is a present-tense sentence. *[Don't] have* is the main verb. *Installed* is an adjective, and the adjectival phrase *installed on my phone* modifies *Instagram*. "What don't I have? Instagram installed on my phone."

> I haven't installed Instagram on my phone.

is a sentence in the present perfect. *Installed* is the a participle, part of the perfect verb phrase *haven't installed*. *On my phone* is a complement of the verb *installed*. "What haven't I installed? Instagram. Where haven't I installed it? On my phone".

The meanings are related, but certainly not the same. If the first is true, then the second is probably true, but not necessarily: maybe I installed it once and then deleted it. (You'd normally use the simple past for that case; *I didn't install Instagram on my phone*; but not necessarily. Perfect tenses can be tricky with negative verbs).

Conversely, the first could be false without the second being false: if the phone came bundled with Instagram, or if somebody else installed it before selling the phone to me, then it will be true that *I haven't installed Instagram on my phone*, but not that *I don't have Instagram installed on my phone*.

Historically, sentences of the first type were the origin of sentences of the second type; but they parted company several centuries ago.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230245/why-cant-i-use-empathic-do-in-present-perfect. I'm confused now

Comment: it says I can't use two auxiliaries.

Comment: _Have_ isn't an auxiliary in the first sentence: it is a full verb.