# Emphasizing a Sentence in Perfect Tense

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-constructions, emphasis

If we want to emphasize the predicate of a simple tense sentence, we only need to add the auxiliary verb “do” (or “did”). Example:

> I came here.
> I did come here. (emphasized)

However, what can we do if we want to emphasize a perfect tense sentence? Consider:

> I have come here.

An answer from a [relevant question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230245/why-cant-i-use-empathic-do-in-present-perfect) tells it’s incorrect to say

> I do have come here. (wrong)

What is the correct auxiliary verb to add, then? Or what else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I did come here" is not general emphasis, it means "Although you think I didn't come here, in fact I did."

> I *have* come here.

The marked stress on the auxiliary has a similar effect to using  "do" in a simple tense. Stress can be indicated in writing by italics or underline, and in speech by intonation and accent.

> Actually, I have come here.

The adverb can also indicate this meaning: that the speaker is contradicting what they think the listener believes.