# Is it possible to emphasise Perfect tenses?

Tags: perfect-constructions, do-support, emphasis

I'm wondering if I could emphasise any sentences in the perfect tense form like when people emphasise the present and the past tenses.

I mean to say, I see a lot of expressions like these:

1. I **do** understand what you are trying to say.
2. She **did** try to call the cops.

Is there any chance I could emphasise this perfect-tense sentence if it's possible?

> I have made a reservation!

Comment: Certainly you can - why do you think you can't?

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, how? Should I say "I *do* have made a reservation"? I'm not sure since I haven't heard someone says like that.

Comment: I see - No, you don't emphasise it using **do**, just "I **have** made a reservation."

Comment: You cannot emphasize it in writing. Only in speech. do works for present simple and did for past simple. The others require changing your intonation.

Comment: This is [related](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230245/why-cant-i-use-empathic-do-in-present-perfect#:~:text=You%20can't%20use%20the,the%20affirmative%20sentences%20for%20emphasis.).

Comment: Basically, you cannot use the *emphatic do* if there is already a modal or other "helping verb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can apply the same emphasis here.  Typically you'd do this when someone is implying that you did not make a reservation, e.g.:

> Them: You're so forgetful; I asked you to book us a table yesterday and you still haven't made a reservation...
>
> You: I **have** made a reservation!

Note that you'd only typically use this form if someone previously said "you haven't made ...".  As a counter-example, if they said "I asked you and you *didn't* make a reservation", then you'd typically respond "I *did* make a reservation" rather than "I *have* made ...".

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty of this question is that perfect tenses already have an emphatic use.

Parent

> I told you to do your homework.

Child

> I **have** done my home work.

But obviously the perfect tenses have other uses, and how do you emphasize them? You need to use other words or phrases.

> I have got home from work and am enjoying some beer.

implies recency.

> I have just got home from work

emphasizes that “recent” means quire recent.

> I have not found my phone

has current relevance.

> I have still not found my phone

implies that the search has been going on for some time (not so recent) but emphasizes its continuing and frustrating relevance,